# How do you unsubscribe from a Firebase realtime listener?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is really confusing/frustrating.

I am trying to unsubscribe from a realtime listener on Cloud Firestore.

Both the official docs as well as the code base comments in the SDK say that the `onSnapshot` function should return an `firebase.Unsubscribe` function that I can call when I'm ready to unsubscribe.

Looking at the actual code though. The `onSnapshot` function clearly returns a `() => Void`

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Does calling the returned `() => void` function unsubscribe you from the listener?

Any help is much appreciated.... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does calling the returned () => void function unsubscribe you from the listener?

Yes, that's exactly the case.